# How to wait the operations until finishing they work using RXJS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, angularfire

> I need a way to wait the RXJS finish his work.

This is my function:

```
      getLastOrderBeta() {
        return this.db.list(`Ring/${localStorage.getItem('localstorage')}`, {
            query: {
              equalTo: false,
              orderByChild: 'status',
              limitToLast: 2,
            }
          })
          .map((orders: any) => {
            return orders.map((order: any) => {
              order.userInfo = this.getProfile(order.userid);
              return order;
            });
          }).do((s:any)=>{
            console.log(s);
            console.log(here);
           }); 
      }
```

When I have one item the log is normal:

[image]

When I have two items same log is normal:

[image]

But when I have three items the log is duplicated:

[image]

Maybe the limit to last causing this issue.
Any help to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: If you know that your `Observable` will complete, then you could `reduce` it, or convert it to a `Promise` using `toPromise`.

Comment: How can I use toPromise

Comment: can u get an example

Comment: You can chain it like any other method (`map`, `filter`, etc). `yourObservable.toPromise()`

Comment: put an answer please explain what you mean, thanks

Comment: I need a method that replace the role of the limit to last

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I posted an answer for the questions title.

Comment: Can I help me to delete the limitToLast from the query and created code to get the last two elements that we can write it inside a map operator ? because the problem is from limitTolast

Comment: Ah, I don't think that has anything to do with Rxjs. Show us the implementation of `db.list`.

Comment: let suppose we have an array,, how can I get the last two elements to it.,, then the code I ll put it inside the map orperator

Comment: Have a look at [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166096/discussion-between-khaled-ramadan-and-balazs-edes).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `getLastOrderBeta` method returns an `Observable` you could transform it to a `Promise` using `toPromise`:

```
const valueAsPromise = getLastOrderBeta().toPromise()
```

This `Promise` will reject if your `Observable` throws anywhere and resolves with the last emitted value.

```
valueAsPromise
  .then((value) => {
     // last value from your observable
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     // something bad happened
  })
```

If you need to wait for multiple emitted values then you can call `toArray` first:

```
const valuesAsPromise = getLastOrderBeta().toArray().toPromise()
```

Which will result in a Promise which resolves with all the emitted values.

If you need custom logic to aggregate the emitted values, use `reduce`.